# How to execute onchanged after a pause in textfield?(Flutter)

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to execute a event when the text of a `TextField` is changed but after a pause.

Suppose, I have a search box but I don't want to change the search data after the user enters each letter but instead the search should take place only if the user entered and paused for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Gunter is correct about using a debounce function, but the one in RxDart only works for `Observable`s (as he pointed out you can convert the onChanged events into a stream and go that route). You can also easily implement your own to accept any function.

```
// Define this function somewhere
import 'dart:async';

// This map will track all your pending function calls
Map<Function, Timer> _timeouts = {};
void debounce(Duration timeout, Function target, [List arguments = const []]) {
  if (_timeouts.containsKey(target)) {
    _timeouts[target].cancel();
  }

  Timer timer = Timer(timeout, () {
    Function.apply(target, arguments);
  });

  _timeouts[target] = timer;
}
```

Then, you can use it like so in your widget

```
void _onChanged(String val) {
  // ...
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...

  TextField(
    // ...
    onChanged: (val) => debounce(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), _onChanged, [val]),
  )

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like `debounce` provided by https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/debounce.html

> ```
> new Observable.range(1, 100)
>   .debounce(new Duration(seconds: 1))
>   .listen(print); // prints 100
> ```

Comment: This debounce function only works on `Observable`s, it can't be used for an onChanged function.

Comment: It's not hard to make a stream from `onChange` and convert that to an `Observable`. I'd prefer such battle-tested code over hand-written custom code, especially if streams are used throughout the application for state management anyway. So I'd say, it depends on the actual use case and personal preferences.

Comment: That's fair, I suppose it depends on OP's preference. Either method will work.